# When are Temp files deleted in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files

I have roughly 100MB of files stored in two temp directories: "C:\Windows\Temp" and "C:\Users\Username\Appdata\Local\Temp"

But unlike their names suggest, they don't seem to be self-cleared even after a long time.
I've tried Disk Cleanup tool with all options checked, but many temp files stay where they were.

and I don't have an idea what to delete manually, having heard about system not functioning properly after accidental deletion.

Why for the love of god are they called "Temp" when they are not?

Comment: I don’t see any relation between them being temporary files and any automatic removal. // 100 MB is next to nothing, it suggests your system is working very well. My work PC has 11 GiB in `%TEMP%` alone.

Comment: The creators of Unix and most(all?) Linux distribution maintainers on the other hand see a strong relation between temporary files and automatic removal. So much so that they chose to delete them on every reboot. I *guess* windows architects feel the same but abstain from deleting them because it is causing problems in some obscure 3rd party program. Sometimes compatibility is a PITA.

Answer (score 3):

Some Windows components and even third-party programs use
temporary files while they are working.

These temporary files are locked, because they are opened for writing
and therefore exclusively. No other program can access these files
as long as the opening program is running (and some such programs are
a part of Windows).

There are therefore always some temporary files that are impossible
to delete. You need to track down the program and kill it if you
wish to delete the files it is using, sometimes causing harm to
Windows.

In conclusion, just ignore these files.

Your other option is to
[Automatically Clean the Windows Temp Folder During Boot](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/create-batch-file-auto-clean-windows-temp-folder/),
but I advise against it, as some of these files may be used by the
program that created them for a smoother startup or recovery.

Windows by default never deletes temporary files. You may clean
them up manually once in a while using the Disk Cleanup tool,
or even manually from Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

"Temporary" files are, more often than not, deleted whenever the program that created them chooses to delete them.

On Linux the "temporary" directories are typically ramdisks, meaning that they are cleared on a reboot. On Windows there is no built-in ramdisk functionality.

As a result on Windows it is down to the programs to be well behaved and clean up after themselves, or for you to occasionally clean them up yourself.

Windows does have a built in "Disk Cleanup" tool which can be used to remove various types of temporary files, from previous windows update installers to image thumbnails.

You can find the tool by either

- opening **Explorer**, right clicking the drive (for example `C:`), then selecting **Properties**. In there should be a "Disk Cleanup" button which will launch the tool.
- alternatively open the start menu and start typing "disk cleanup" and you should find the tool that way.